# Changing color of 3D columns in Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Google Chart to graph some data, and I want to customize colors. I also would like to use 3D bars (which means I cannot use core library BTW).

This is a screencap of the results I am getting:

[image]

Left is the original 3D chart, right is the customized one. As you can see, no shading is applied to the color I define for the 3D effect, instead a flat color is used for the whole column.

Is there any way to fix this?

PS. this is the code I use to geneate the charts:

```
function drawChartCoste(){
        // Create the data table.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'Valor');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Grupo1');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Grupo2');
          data.addRow(['Consumo', 2.5, -17.860);


          // Set chart options
          var options = {'title':'Comparativa de coste',
                         'width':400,
                         'height':300,
                         'is3D':true,
                         'colors':['#C26900','#165C04']};

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Comment: There are [many reasons](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-3d-charts-charts-with-no-value/) not to use 3d charts. Not that this will necessarily change your mind. In the meantime, please include the code you used to create your chart so we can at least work from the same baseline.

Comment: Unfortunately is not up to me whether to switch from 3D to 2D. I posted the function I use to generate the charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I firmly restate my opposition to 3d charts, it would seem that this is doable [from this line in the Docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart_old):

> If is3D=true, this is an array of either HTML colors, or objects of this type: `{color:face_color, darker:shade_color}` where color is the element's face color, and darker is the shade color. However, if you specify an HTML color for a 3D object, face and shade will be the same color, and the 3D effect will be reduced. Example: `{is3D:true, colors:[{color:'#FF0000', darker:'#680000'}, {color:'cyan', darker:'deepskyblue'}]}`

Here is a sample:

```
    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Comparativa de coste',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300,
                   is3D:true,
                   colors:[{color:'#C26900', darker:'#B15800'}, {color:'#165C04', darker:'#054B00'}]
                  };
```

Comment: No problem -- it's hidden because it's deprecated. I hope that it works out for you!